# Is it possible to find extrema of solution of first order ODE  without solving ODE?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hello everyone,

Sorry maybe question quite stupid.
I have first order, scalar ODE:
$$ \frac{du}{dt}=u_{\infty}(t)-u $$
where $u_{\infty}(t)$ is really heavy, so I'm pretty sure, that there is not any way to resolve classical integral. I need to find value of solution in exttrema $t_X$, specifically in maximum. Obviously that in extremal points: $u_{\infty}(t_X)=u(t_X)$, so if we can get $t_X$, we would easy get $u(t_X)$. 
We can define initial condition as $u(0) = u_{\infty}(0) = E$, where E - some constant.

Do anyone have any idea how to get $t_X$ without resolving $u(t)$?

Just note that, if we will looking for standard solution:
 $$u(t) = e^{-t}\left( \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} u_{\infty}(x)e^x dx + C\right) $$
at $t_X$:
$$ u_{\infty}(t_X)e^{t_X} = \int\limits_0^{t_X} u_{\infty}(x)e^x dx + C $$
Can we estimate where function $\left(F(t)=u_{\infty}(t)e^{t} \right)$ intersects its integral value  and then estimate $C$ from initial condition?

I'll appreciate any help.

Ruben

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "heavy" or "unresolvable".  If closed-form solutions are unavailable, have you tried numerical methods?

Comment: The solution and also the extrema will depend on the initial condition for $u$. If you're just looking for an extremal value, then for any $t_X$ you can find $u_0$ such that $u(t)$ is extremal at $t_X$. This can easily be seen by writing down the variation of constants integral solution.

Comment: to Robert: The point is that: I have to solve it analytically, because it is a checker for my numerical results. 'Heavy' or 'unresolvable' means that, standard solution
$$ u(t) = e^{-t}\, \int_{-\infty}^{t} u_{\infty}(x)e^{x}dx $$
is hardly resolvable.

Comment: to Jaap: Thank you for comment, you are absolutely right. Solution should obey to some initial condition. $u(-\infty) = E$, where E is a constant, BTW $u_{\infty}(-\infty) = u_{\infty}(\infty) = E$, where E is the same constant.

Comment: An "initial condition" at $-\infty$ or $+\infty$ generally does not lead to a well-posed problem.  Typically either solutions don't have a limit as $t \to -\infty$, or all solutions will have the same limit.  In this case the homogeneous equation has a solution $u(t) = e^{-t}$ which goes to $+\infty$ as $t \to -\infty$; there will be at most one solution to your non-homogeneous equation that goes to a finite value as $t \to -\infty$, but there may be none.

Comment: But if in fact the solution you want is
$u(t)=e^{-t} \int_{-\infty}^t u_\infty(x) e^x\ dx$
(which, of course, assumes that this improper integral converges), then you might try the change of variables $v=e^x$, which gives you an integral over a finite interval
$$u(t)=e^{−t}\int_0^{\exp(t)} u_\infty(ln(v))\ dv$$
This may be more amenable to numerical methods.

Comment: to Robert, Re "An initial condition": I know, but it's best that we have. If you can suggest something like sigmoid function, or $(\tanh(t)+1)/2$, which can touch zero and one not at infinity, we can definitely try to use it. Our current $u_{\infty}(t)$, limited on $\pm \infty, \, u_{\infty}(\pm \infty) = E$, where $E$ is a constant, it has only two extrema and no singular points; it is smooth and always differentiable. We need only extremal values of solution.

Comment: to Robert, Re  " try the change of variables": Thank you so much! It looks nice and will work hopefully. I'll try it. I've never heard about this, probably it is standard trick. 

Comment: to Robert: Unfortunately it doesn't work for such $u_{\infty}$. 